# Having problems removing a string from a sting list

Tags: c#, list

I want to remove an item from a list...

I am obviously missing something...I have tried just about every variation including EXCEPT, REMOVE, etc...

When debugging, I step through each ling, but when it gets to btnRemove_Click, it steps through removing but does not remove anything...it acts as if I never sent a command to remove anything???

Help!

```
public partial class frmUpdate : Form
{
    private Student student = new Student();
    private string _scores;

    public frmUpdate()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string GetUpdatedScores(Student s)
    {
        txtName.Text = s.Name;
        _scores = s.Scores;        
        FillStudentGrades();
        this.ShowDialog();
        return _scores;


    }

    private void FillStudentGrades()
    {
        lstScores.Items.Clear();
        string[] grades = splitGrades(_scores);
        foreach (string s in grades)
        {
            lstScores.Items.Add(s.ToString());
        }       
    }

    private void lstScores_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = lstScores.SelectedIndex;
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmAddScore addScore = new frmAddScore();
        _scores += " " + addScore.AddScore();
        FillStudentGrades();
    }

    private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = lstScores.SelectedIndex;

    }

    private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = lstScores.SelectedIndex;

    }

    private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lstScores.SelectedIndex < 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You Must Select A Grade.");
            btnUpdate.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            int i = lstScores.SelectedIndex;
            string[] grades = splitGrades(_scores);
            string message = "Are you sure you want to remove " + grades[i].ToString() + "?";
            DialogResult button = MessageBox.Show(message, "Confirm Remove",
                MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (button == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                int count = 0;
                foreach (char c in grades[i])
                {
                    if (char.IsDigit(c))
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                int a = _scores.IndexOf(grades[i].ToString());
                _scores = _scores.Remove(a, (count + 1));
                FillStudentGrades();
                btnOk.Focus();
            }
            else
            {
                btnOk.Focus();
            }
        }
    }

    private void btnClearAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        student.Name = txtName.Text;
        student.Scores = _scores;
        this.Close();
    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    public string[] splitGrades(string s)
    {
        string[] grades = s.Split(' ');
        return grades;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure that SelectedIndex> 0

Comment: you need to specify the Index position look at `_scores = _scores.Remove(i);` Edward provides an accurate example

Comment: Yes, very sure about the selectedindex...but I can add an if statement to make sure a grade has been selected in the lstbox...

Comment: updated to make sure list item has been selected...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C#, strings are immutable. `_scores.Remove(i);` doesn't change `_scores`. Instead it returns a new string object that you can assign to a variable, for example, back to `_scores` like this:

```
_scores = _scores.Remove(i);
```

Comment: That headed me in the right direction I think...but now when I update a score, it clears all the scores except a "7"...???   I will edit the above code showing the revised code...

Comment: @Jerry: The one-parameter overload of `String.Remove` removes all characters at an index to the end of the string. Use the overload that accepts two parameters to specify how many characters to remove.

Comment: almost there...(thank you thank you)...now I am having trouble removing the correct string from the list...the separator is a space so I have a count + 1 to remove the string and the space that follows...but I it seems to always remove the 2nd item in the list...? I have update the code above...

Comment: thank you, Edward...you put me on the right path and figured out a solution...I am sure as I advance I will figure out cleaner and smoother ways to write the code...

Answer (score 0):

you need to use RemoveAt methos - as you are trying to remove index and not the value